# How to write dynamic log file names with log4js-node?

Tags: node.js, dynamic, log4js-node

I am trying to write a log file based on the time-stamp of the code when it runs.
The log writes very well when the name is set, for example "Test.log":

```
const appSettings = {
        log4js: {
            traceLogConfig: {
                appenders: {
                    fileAppender: { type: 'file', filename: `./logs/Test.log`},
                    consoleAppender: { type: 'console' }
            },
            categories: {
                default: { appenders: ['fileAppender', 'consoleAppender'], level: 'trace'}
            }
        }
    }
};
```

A log file with the name is created correctly in the "logs" folder, and is filled with the logs from the code.
However, things get more complicated when I try to make the name dynamic:

```
const appSettings = {
        log4js: {
            traceLogConfig: {
                appenders: {
                    fileAppender: { type: 'file', filename: `./logs/${new Date().toISOString().toString().replace(":","-")}`},
                    consoleAppender: { type: 'console' }
            },
            categories: {
                default: { appenders: ['fileAppender', 'consoleAppender'], level: 'trace'}
            }
        }
    }
};
```

When I run this, the file is created correctly in the folder, but then it is not filled with the log entries when the code runs.
I tried creating the name separately and placing it into the code:

```
let name = new Date().toISOString().toString().replace(":","-");

const appSettings = {
        log4js: {
            traceLogConfig: {
                appenders: {
                    fileAppender: { type: 'file', filename: `./logs/${name}`},
                    consoleAppender: { type: 'console' }
            },
            categories: {
                default: { appenders: ['fileAppender', 'consoleAppender'], level: 'trace'}
            }
        }
    }
};
```

But this did not solve the issue either.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Apparently, it's not possible to pass a dynamic file name. You need to use a placeholder property with multiFile and then pass the property name (from the [documentation](https://github.com/log4js-node/log4js-node/blob/f8d46a939279c0ab4efc8bb5f0478c4b0949a4cf/docs/multiFile.md)):

```
log4js.configure({
  appenders: {
    everything: {
      type: 'multiFile', base: 'logs/', property: 'userID', extension: '.log',
      maxLogSize: 10485760, backups: 3, compress: true
    }
  },
  categories: {
    default: { appenders: [ 'everything' ], level: 'debug'}
  }
});

const userLogger = log4js.getLogger('user');
userLogger.addContext('userID', user.getID());
userLogger.info('this user just logged in');
```

Answer (score 1):

This can be done.

Let your log4js config file be as it is:

```
       const appSettings = {
                log4js: {
                    traceLogConfig: {
                        appenders: {
                            fileAppender: { type: 'file', filename: `./logs/Test.log`},
                            consoleAppender: { type: 'console' }
                    },
                    categories: {
                        default: { appenders: ['fileAppender', 'consoleAppender'], level: 'trace'}
                    }
                }
            }
        };
module.exports = appSettings;
```

You can overwrite the file name while loading the configuration as below:

```
const { traceLogConfig } = require('./log4js-config').log4js;
traceLogConfig.appenders.fileAppender.filename = 'your file name';
log4js.configure(traceLogConfig);
```